# Jquery searching an element for two sets of strings

Tags: jquery, string, contains

Trying to get Jquery to run a search against a string that is loaded from a combination of two variables.

Here's some more code below for more context.
The objective of this code is to search the SharePoint table for both a value that is given by pressing a button, as well as a value that the user can optionally type.  The user can search by either using only the search input (txt variable) or the buttons.

```
var ButtonValue = null
$("#button1").click(function(){


            $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

             $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

            $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

            $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

            $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

            $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show()
             ButtonValue = "Faucets" 

             });

$("input.search").change(function() {
              var txt = $("input.search").val();



        if (txt) {
              //alert("VN : " + VN);
              //alert(".change() called");

             //Vendor List
             $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+" )").show();

             //Manufacturer Reps
             // Logic to see search value is numeric then search using the company name
             $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+")").show();

             //Vendor Contact List
             $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+")").show();

             //Vendor Document List
             $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+")").show();

             // Vendor Details
             $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+")").show();

             // Product Lines
             $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
             $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+ "+ButtonValue+"")").show();

            } else {

              $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
              $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
              $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
              $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
              $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
              $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();           
            }
          }).keyup(function(){$(this).change();
         });


$("#button1").click(function() {
      $.ajax('/forward');
      $('button1').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Contains would look for exact match to the string. It's that what your trying to achieve ?

Comment: @DinoMyte Nope. Not an an exact match. Would the correct way to do this be 'like'?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a '+' on your first line right before the txt variable:

```
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").hide();
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+" "+ButtonValue+"))").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for either one of the text occurrence, you need to define 2 separate `:contains` selectors.

```
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover td").hide();
$("#WebPartWPQ5 tr.ms-itmhover td:contains("+txt+"), #WebPartWPQ5 tr.ms-itmhover td:contains("+ButtonValue+")").show();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/uyk0kopq/2/

Comment: Thank you.  That didn't quite work how I wanted it to for my application..It's in a SharePoint table and it's supposed to return an entire row based on this query that has the specified strings.  Any ideas?

Comment: 'contains' is used for string lookups. Are txt, ButtonValue html elements inside the tr ?

Comment: Yes they are.  The query I posted above does work without the 'ButtonValue' variable.  I'm having trouble adding the additional condition of 'ButtonValue' to the query.

Comment: It would be really hard to find the exact problem without the underlying html. Any chance you could add it to the question ?

Comment: I've added it.  Thanks for your help.